# Spring mvc Time column receiving null cause HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using spring mvc with hibernate on mysql database.
In one of the tables there is a column **EndTime** of type **time**, which could be null.

I mapped it to my java class with the type **java.sql.Time**.

Getting data from the table goes well, but when I try to add rows with empty value in this specific column, it fails with the following error:

```
...
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message": "Could not read JSON: Instantiation of [simple type, class java.sql.Time] value failed: null (through reference chain: mediamatrix.models.playlists.MediaAd[\"endTime\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class java.sql.Time] value failed: null (through reference chain: mediamatrix.models.playlists.MediaAd[\"endTime\"])",
...
```

For using this payload from the client:

```
{"a":10100,"b":4667,...,"endTime":""}
```

If I add value to the endTime property it executes without an issue.

Does anybody knows why this is happening? Tried to check for null in the setter methods of the class, but it doesn't even call it, just produce the error.

Thanks.

PS.
Relevant snippets of code:

Table mapping class:
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name = "atable")
public class ATable {

    @Column(name = "a")
    int a;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "b")
    int b;

    ...

    @Column(name = "EndTime")
    Time EndTime;

    ...

    public Time getEndTime() {
        return EndTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(Time endTime) {
//        if (endTime != null) {
        EndTime = endTime;
//        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addATableItem", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> AddATableItem(@RequestBody ATable aItem) {
        return _session.addATableItem(aItem);
}
```

Hibernate handling:

```
public Map<String, Object> addATableItem(ATable atable) {
        Map<String, Object> res = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            this.getSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO atable (... EndTime) VALUES (... :EndTime)")
                    ...
                    .setParameter("EndTime", atable.getEndTime()).executeUpdate();
            res.put("status", 1);
            res.put("message", "success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            res.put("status", 0);
            res.put("message", "failure");
        }
        return res;
}
```

Comment: Spring doesn't know how to convert java.sql.Time to a JSon. You can convert it yourself to a String, or use a normal java.util.Date instead.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I tried using Date object, but it doesn't recognize the time format in the json (HH:mm:ss e.g 13:00:00).
This is the error message:
    "...Can not construct instance of java.sql.Date from String value '13:00:00': not a valid representation ...".

Also the Time object does work, only when the field is null the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found what the issue was, note that in the payload I sent the endTime value is equal to an empty string rather than null, when I changed it to null, spring accepted it!